# The proof of Banach-Tarski paradox on Wikipedia

Tags: measure-theory, paradoxes

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#Step_3

In the part of the proof that deals with the fixed points on $S^2$, the page says "Let $\lambda$ be some line through the origin that does not intersect any point in $D$. This is possible since $D$ is countable." where $D$ is the set of the fixed points. Could you formally explain why we can find such line that does not intersect any point in $D$? My understanding is that since $S^2$ is a uncountable set, there are infinitely many points on $S^2$ that are not in $D$. But I don't know how to explain such line through origin can intersect with $S^2$ on "two" points that are not in %D%.

The next line of the proof is "Let $J$ be the set of angles, $\alpha$, such that for some natural number $n$, and some $P$ in $D$, $r(n\alpha)P$ is also in $D$, where $r(n\alpha)$ is a rotation about $\lambda$ of $n\alpha$. Then $J$ is countable." Exactly why is $J$ countable?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For the first part - you are right in that since there are uncountably many points in $S^2$, avoiding countably many is fine. The point is that there are also uncountably many possible $\textit{lines}$ going through (at least) one point not in $D$, since (informally) "removing countably many points from an uncountable set leaves uncountably many points remaining". So if every such line also went through a point in $D$, this would imply that $D$ is uncountable.

Comment: Or in fact, an easier way to say it is that there must be uncountably many antipodal pairs in $S^2 \setminus D$, for the same reasons.

Comment: @Stuartg98 your explanation is so clear that now I have no problem at all with the first part! Could you also help me with the second part?

Comment: Have added an answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, I will repeat my answer from comments above - the point is that there are also uncountably many possible lines going through (at least) one point not in D, since (informally) "removing countably many points from an uncountable set leaves uncountably many points remaining". So if every such line also went through a point in D, this would imply that D is uncountable.

For the second part, we first fix a point $P$ of $D$ (if we can show the set of rotations about $P$ taking $P$ to another point of $D$ is countable, since $D$ is countable we will be done). Denote by $J_P$ the subset of $J$ of the angles $\alpha$ corresponding to rotations from $P$. Well, we know there are only countably many points in $D$, so in particular there are only countably many angles $\beta$ which we can rotate $P$ by to obtain another point of $D$. Now, each $\beta$ is in $J_P$, but we also have $$\beta = 2 \cdot (\beta/2) = 3 \cdot (\beta/3) = \ ... \ ,$$ so in fact each $\alpha_{\beta,n} := \beta/n$ is in $J_P$ too. But for each $\beta$, the set of $\alpha_{\beta,n}$ is countable, and I claim that $J_P = \{ \alpha_{\beta,n} \}$; indeed, if $\alpha$ is a rotation in $J_P$, then $n \alpha = \beta$ for some $n$ and angle $\beta$ as above. Thus $J_P$ is in particular countable (we can index this set by $(\beta,n) \in \{\text{these countably many angles} \ \beta \} \times \mathbb{Z}$, a countable set).

Since $J_P$ is countable for each $P$, and $D$ is countable, we deduce that $J$ is countable. More formally, we can index $D$ as $D = \{P_i \}_{i} = \{P_1, P_2, \ ... \}$. Then $J = J_{P_1} \cup J_{P_2} \cup \ ...$ is countable, since (assuming the axiom of choice) the countable union of countable sets is countable (see: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Union_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable).

Hope this makes sense! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, consider the partition of $S^2$ in sets whit form $\{z,-z\}$ where if $z=(x,y)$, then $-z=(-x,-y)$. It is easy to see that this partition is uncountable. As $D$ is countable, it intersect only whit countably many elements of the partition. So, we can choose a pair $\{z,-z\}$ such that $\{z,-z\}\cap D=\emptyset$. If $\lambda$ is the line that join this pair of points ($z$ and $-z$), then this line satisfies that you require.